# Sketch - Line linked to other objects

Tags: sketch-app, diagram

Let's say I build a diagram with list of items (text), every text is linked with line to another to show relation. How can I snap line to text object, so when moving text, line will follow it's position? (another end of line will stick to other label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK line endpoints can't be linked to objects in Sketch. You can't even select a line endpoint and an object at the same time. This would work in Adobe Illustrator.

If you have to work a lot with diagrams, you might want to look for special diagram software. There are free online tools like https://www.draw.io/, open source and commercial tools which would do what you need. They probably all export to SVG, so you can place the results in Sketch afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

What AAGD has said is true.

You can try using a plugin or a library with moderate success rate:
https://sketchflowkit.com/ seems to work well and looks awesome. 
also https://abynim.github.io/UserFlows/ - there's a plugin that can help with some flowcharts.

Let me know if this helped!